# Endpoint-specific timeouts in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I want something like an endpoint-specific timeout definition. For example I have two different endpoints: Endpoint 1 is used after the API start to warm-up and load all the informations. For this request I have a lot of time. The second endpoint is used in production. I expect an response within a second otherwise I want the timeout. So that I can continue with the next requests.

Is there a way in FastAPI to define something like that?

Answer (score 1):

In fastapi we can use uvicorn module..which has timeout param...

uvicorn main:app --port 44444 --host 0.0.0.0 --reload --log-level debug

From the uvicorn docs:

--timeout-keep-alive  - Close Keep-Alive connections if no new data is received within this timeout. Default: 5